# Form data not being posted to the database

Tags: angularjs, mean-stack

I'm having some trouble capturing the data in my form and sending it to the server. I tested the end point and that worked fine and if I place dummy values in angular and submit that seems to work fine but when I try to get the values from my form all I get back are blank objects.

```
{
    "_id": "5a6ed91d37fcd13024593b78",
    "__v": 0
}
```

Express Route

```
router.post('/booking/addReservation', function (req, res, next) {
 Booking.create(req.body, function (err, post) {
    if(err) return next(err);
    res.json(post);
  });
});
```

Angular Factory

```
app.factory('postReservationOne', function ($resource) {
return $resource('http://localhost:5016/api/booking/addReservation')
});
```

Controller

```
app.controller('addReservationOne', function ($scope, postReservationOne) {

$scope.reservation = {};
$scope.newReservation = function () {
    var reservationOne = new postReservationOne($scope.reservation);
    reservationOne.$save();
}
});
```

Form

```
 <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="First Name" 
        name="firstName" ng-required="true"
        ng-model="reservation.firstName">
 <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Last Name"
        name="lastName" ng-required="true"
        ng-model="reservation.lastName">
 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"
         ng-controller="addReservationOne"
         ng-click="newReservation()">Submit</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The controller should encapsulate the form:

```
<div ng-controller="addReservationOne">
  <form name="form1">
     <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="First Name" 
            name="firstName" ng-required="true"
            ng-model="reservation.firstName">
     <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Last Name"
            name="lastName" ng-required="true"
            ng-model="reservation.lastName">
     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"
             ̶n̶g̶-̶c̶o̶n̶t̶r̶o̶l̶l̶e̶r̶=̶"̶a̶d̶d̶R̶e̶s̶e̶r̶v̶a̶t̶i̶o̶n̶O̶n̶e̶"̶
             ng-click="newReservation()">Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Also the controller should use the factory to create the `reservation` object:

```
app.controller('addReservationOne', function ($scope, postReservationOne) {

    $scope.reservation = ̶{̶}̶;̶ new postReservationOne();
    $scope.newReservation = function () {
        ̶v̶a̶r̶ ̶r̶e̶s̶e̶r̶v̶a̶t̶i̶o̶n̶O̶n̶e̶ ̶=̶ ̶n̶e̶w̶ ̶p̶o̶s̶t̶R̶e̶s̶e̶r̶v̶a̶t̶i̶o̶n̶O̶n̶e̶(̶$̶s̶c̶o̶p̶e̶.̶r̶e̶s̶e̶r̶v̶a̶t̶i̶o̶n̶)̶;̶
        ̶r̶e̶s̶e̶r̶v̶a̶t̶i̶o̶n̶O̶n̶e̶.̶$̶s̶a̶v̶e̶(̶)̶;̶
        //Save the Resource object
        reservation.$save();
    }
});
```

For more information, see [AngularJS ngResource $resource API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource)

Answer (score 1):

I'm a little rusty with my angular, but I believe this is because you are creating a new `$scope` here. In your code example, I see your `ng-controller` is sitting on the button.

Your form elements are modifying the outer `$scope.reservation` values, but leaving the "inner" `$scope` (the button) untouched. My guess is that if you throw a `debugger` or `console.log` inside of the `newReservation` function, you'll see that `$scope.reservation` is empty.

Try wrapping your form elements with a tag that includes the `addReservationOne` controller on it instead of the button.

```
<form ng-controller="addReservationOne">
  <input ng-model="reservation.firstName">
  <!-- etc -->
</form>
```